# Android layout width?

Tags: android

When making the android application layouts we have to define the layout width , what is the meaning of the  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` ?

Answer (score 6):

Either attribute can be applied to View's (visual control) horizontal or vertical size. It's used to set a View or Layouts size based on either it's contents or the size of it's parent layout rather than explicitly specifying a dimension.

**fill_parent**

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in.

Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

**wrap_content**

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

see the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) for more details!

Answer (score 2):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` means that the layout is fixed it expand up to exactly as your content size .If your content is more it expand up to that limit and same as in short content.
 Here is an example..

```
<RelativeLayout  

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button ABC"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`wrap_content` Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`wrap_content` means that width is determined by the width of the widgets, respectively not the whole display' width but only how widgets need.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_width):

**android:layout_width**

> Specifies the basic width of the view. This is a required attribute
> for any view inside of a containing layout manager. Its value may be a
> dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant width or one of the special
> constants. May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number
> appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px
> (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on
> preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters). This may also be
> a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or
> theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a
> value of this type. May be one of the following constant values.
>
> - **fill_parent** -1   The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent.
> - **match_parent**    -1   The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). Introduced in API Level 8.
> - **wrap_content**    -2   The view should be only big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
means that layout width is not determined or fixed, it will take space according to its components.
Suppose in a textField u have only one word then your textField will take space for a word only and then it will take space for two word if you have two word in your textField when you will declare your width as wrap_content.
Same thing is applicable for layout_height also.